# Overwrite haml-rails scaffold templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, haml

I want to customize the controller views generated by [haml-rails](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails). According to the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) I am supposed to put my customized templates (e.g. `index.html.haml`) into `lib/templates/[subfolders]`.

In this case I tried several subfolders (e.g. `lib/templates/haml/scaffold`, `lib/generators/haml/scaffold/templates`) but I could not get my custom templates to be used.

I know that I could write another generator easily, but I am wondering if there is a more DRY way to do so. In theory it should be possible:

> In Rails 3.0 and above, generators don't just look in the source root for templates, they also search for templates in other paths.

I am using `Rails (4.2.5.2)`, `haml (4.0.7)` and `haml-rails (0.9.0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holy moly. It worked after all. It is correct to put the templates into `lib/templates/haml/scaffold`. And now comes the catch: [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) will cache the templates. Hence, you must either restart spring after changes or prepend `DISABLE_SPRING` to the generator command:

```
DISABLE_SPRING=true rails g scaffold ...
```